# Actix_web server to fetch its own tls certs

Tags: ssl, rust, actix-web, acme

I am working on a Webserver which will provide differnt endpoints using https. The Server itself is running fine, but I want to add the auto-reneval of the tls certs using let's encrypt to the server, which I have no idea how to do this.

I've stumbled over some crates which provide such possibilities out of the box but I was not able to integrate them yet. Some of the Following:

- [acme_micro](https://docs.rs/acme-micro/latest/acme_micro/index.html) uses OpenSSL which is bad bc. of cross-compiling
- [rustls_acme](https://docs.rs/rustls-acme/latest/rustls_acme/) where I dont know how to combine this with the server (see below)
- [tide_acme](https://docs.rs/tide-acme/latest/tide_acme/) which is build for tide and not actix

The most promising was rustls_acme but I really dont know how to combine this into the actix server together with actix_web::server::HttpServer::bind_rustls.

Currently I use locally stored key and cert for the rustls config exactly like in the [example](https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/master/https-tls/rustls/src/main.rs).

```
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let (i_cfg, app_data) = init().expect("Server initialization FAILED!");
    let _log = init_logger(&i_cfg).expect("Logger Initialisation Failed!");

    let state = web::Data::new(app_data);
    
    return HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .wrap(middleware::Compress::default())
            .app_data(state.clone())
            .route("/api/time", web::get().to(time))
            .route("/api/echo", web::get().to(echo))
            .route("/api/ship", web::get().to(ship))
            .default_service(web::get().to(not_found))
    })
    .bind_rustls(i_cfg.ip_port, i_cfg.rustls_cfg)?
    .workers(i_cfg.workers)
    .run()
    .await;
}
```

How can I achieve auto-reneval of tls certs using let'sEcnrypt with actix_web and rustls?

Is there a specific crate for actix which I just missed?

Bonus points if:

- No server downtime needed
- Multiple domains possible
- Directly via port 443 (TLS-ALPN-01)

Thanks and Greets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an official example that integrates letsencrypt with actix-web (https://github.com/actix/examples/tree/master/https-tls/acme-letsencrypt). This does restart the server, however.

```
let _auto_shutdown_task = rt::spawn(async move {
    // Shutdown server every 4 weeks so that TLS certs can be regenerated if
    // needed. This is only appropriate in contexts like Kubernetes which
    // can orchestrate restarts.
    rt::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(60 * 60 * 24 * 28)).await;
    srv_handle.stop(true).await;
});
```

It should be possible to avoid that by

1. Integrating the acme-challenge endpoint into the main server
2. Running the fetch-workflow periodically
3. Replacing `config.with_single_cert(...)` with `config.with_cert_resolver(...)` in `load_rustls_config`.